# how to prevent Angular table header is repeating

Tags: html, angular, html-table, ngfor

[image: this is the data Object][image: this is the code output but I want all the data in one table header]

```
<div *ngFor = "let recordData of employees.record">
<div *ngIf = 'recordData.queryName==="style-size-query"'>

  <table class ="table">

    <thead>

    <tr> product  </tr>
    <tr> size  </tr>
    <tr> sortOrder  </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> {{recordData.data.product}}  </td>
        <td> {{recordData.data.size}}  </td>
        <td> {{recordData.data.sortOrder}}  </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div> 
</div>
```

// **this is Angular code and this is the output this code is working but table header data is repeating after the each iteration.

I used ngFor for iteration the record array (it is in the first photo) loop. I used the ngIf to select the queryName and there are six record will come (it is in the first photo). I want that six record under a one table
**

Comment: Provide full code. I can't see any for loop here

Comment: Put your loop (*ngFor) on <tbody> instead of outside the table

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

*Just moved structural directives and used **ng-container** to use **ngIf** and **ngFor***

I don't want to add extra element like div or span to apply **ngIf** and **ngFor** condition. that's why I used **ng-container.**

```
<div>
<div>

  <table class ="table">

    <thead>

    <tr> product  </tr>
    <tr> size  </tr>
    <tr> sortOrder  </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

          <ng-container *ngFor = "let recordData of employees.record">
             <ng-container *ngIf = 'recordData.queryName==="style-size-query"'>
              <tr>
                <td> {{recordData.data.product}}  </td>
                <td> {{recordData.data.size}}  </td>
                <td> {{recordData.data.sortOrder}}  </td>
              </tr>
             </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use the ngFor inside the tbody because in the first photo I used ngFor for loop the record array so ngFor can't used the inside the tbody

Comment: Create stackblitz example with your issue, Will fix and provide you the answer

Comment: @NisalJayathilaka If you can't able to create Stackblitz example, Just provide Whole HTML code(at least code which covers your concerns) and mention your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
  <table class ="table">

    <thead>

    <tr> product  </tr>
    <tr> size  </tr>
    <tr> sortOrder  </tr>
    </thead>
<div *ngIf = 'recordData.queryName==="style-size-query"'>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> {{recordData.data.product}}  </td>
        <td> {{recordData.data.size}}  </td>
        <td> {{recordData.data.sortOrder}}  </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</div> 
  </table>
```

Comment: in here the table already created. but  In my case if there is a data table will create and data will display so ngIf should be add on the top